# `wc -c` gives un expected results?

Tags: command-line, cat, wc

I have a .log file which is a binary file(BSC0000.log). So Viewed it in a HEX viewer(OKteta) and exported it directly in to a string(split_space.txt). With spaces in the middle as 
`00 DF 00 45`.

The thing is that when I counted the characters in both file it showed a huge difference.

```
laksith@laksithPC:~/Desktop/test$ cat split_space.txt | wc -c
31617470
laksith@laksithPC:~/Desktop/test$ cat BSC0000.log | wc -c
10539157
```

A guess can be made that it might be because of the spaces in between
. But then it should be roughly like 10539157 + 10539157/2 but how come it be this value 31617470.

but 10539157 * 3 = 31617471   that is the value from the command line +1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A byte has 8 bits.  Because hex uses 16 characters, 0-9a-f, it can only display  four bits per character.  *It takes two hex characters to display one byte.*  Add to that that most characters in the hex display have a space after them and you see why the hex display takes up to three times as many bytes as the binary file.

#### Example

Let's create a file containing a single byte:

```
$ printf 'a' >afile
$ wc afile
0 1 1 afile
```

Now, let's display it with, for example, `hexdump -C`:

```
$ hexdump -C afile
00000000  61                                                |a|
00000001
```

The `a` character is ASCII character `61` (hex).  The single byte in the file takes two characters to display in hex (and three if the hex has a space after it).

Comment: does HEX has spaces in the middle? I dought it. How come hex file contain spaces as spaces are also stored in HEX values. ?

Comment: @Laksith Yes.  The hex with spaces is a _display_ format.  It is done to be easy for humans to read.  It is not how the data is stored in a file.